# App Domain field is not accepting our Appstore URL

Tags: flutter, facebook, facebook-ads-api

As per the [Facebook documentation for App Events (iOS)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios)
 it mentioned `App Domains - Provide Apple App Store URL of your app`

But [App Domain field is not accepting our Appstore URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkl2n.png).

Actually when I am trying to run iOS campaigns on Facebook we are unable to advertise it to the latest models of iOS and the Facebook is showing this below message -

> It seems that your iTunes Account is not yet registered in Facebook Developer. You might need to register first so that when you type the iTunes ID and link in the field, it will show the result. Here's the link where you can follow the steps on how to register the iTunes to Facebook Developer: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/444614902378217?id=1858550721111595

But we have setup the iOS platform in the app as per the above documentation except that App Domain field. So I am think due to the App Domain field Facebook is showing this message.

The mobile app is on Flutter and we have used [facebook_app_events](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events)

Am I doing something wrong here?